# Searching docs for jboss forge

Tags: jboss-forge

a few weeks ago I stumbled upon jboss forge - seems to be a cool tool, but I miss documentation beyond the tutorials.

Is there somewhere a more detailed documentation or maybe a book that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three easy ways to learn about Forge:

1. Read the available documentation in [the website](http://forge.jboss.org/documentation)
2. Practice the [Hands-on Lab](http://forge.jboss.org/document/hands-on-lab)
3. Watch the videos in [the Forge Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChnruRwagWHn16cNSOH_Atw/videos)

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: the Hand-on Lab looks good. I guess that was what I was searching for... thanx!

Comment: just printed the lab docs for the weekend. It is huge - nearly a book! yes, that's the right answer...